# How to construct a //g command with WorldEdit in minecraft for a Conical Spiral or Spherical Spiral

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-worldedit

I am trying to convert the equations for a conical spiral (base on a Fermat's spiral
Or ideally a way to gradually make a spherical spiral ([Spherical Spiral](https://medium.com/geekculture/spiral-curves-for-robotics-in-c-9c3d80abe4d1))) in to minecraft's world edit command: [Generate](https://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/16cakdr/world_edit_commands_generate_making_a/)

Can someone help me format it please.

[image: spherical Spiral equation][image: Spherical Spiral Result]

There is a simliar question [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/47384/how-to-construct-a-g-command-with-worldedit-in-minecraft)  Which is useful, and has an answer from Kevin Reid and I can see it might guide someone to the answer. However accepting my limitations, Im autistic and ADHD and quite honestly just "not smart enough to understand the equations" I am really struggling to get there.

References:

This is a Cylindrical Helix:

```
//g -hc diamond_block rotate(x,z,pi*y/60); z/=2; x+=15; x^2+z^2<8^2
```

This is a Cone:

```
//g -hc diamond_block type=((x^2+z^2<y^2)&&(y<0))?22:0
```

Aaand a bunch of commands from a youtube video [Here](https://pastebin.com/9XqgMKnn)

[World edit Commands](https://worldedit.enginehub.org/en/latest/commands/)
[Expression Syntax](https://worldedit.enginehub.org/en/latest/usage/other/expressions/)
[Conical Spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conical_spiral)

Comment: For anyone that comes to find more information on this a good video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7QfgRuryFwg

Comment: While I think this should indeed be on-topic here, you might get better answers elsewhere, where users are likely a bit more mathematics-savvy. I suggest asking this at [GameDev](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) first.

Comment: I have asked this a couple of other places and gotten precisely 0 answers :)  I will try your advice in a short bit though .. gonna pick up my son .. thanks for the look. 

Andy

Comment: Just in case anyone find this in the future. I've found a useful document which I will include to help. 

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1-o4dyb0ahlnn4tDgWfoTvUEQ2yBKDx_9qnUFWMJXgY0/edit